# Add drive to Logwatch disk space check

Tags: centos, lvm, logwatch

I'm looking to add a LVM volume to a Logwatch report for a Xen dom0. Currently this LVM volume doesn't show in the report as it is not mounted on the machine but is a physical drive. Any ideas on how to accomplish that?

I have no other reason for this drive to be mounted (it is used for domU's). Open to suggestions!

Comment: What do you expect logwatch to do with an unmounted LV?  Does it even have a filesystem on it?

Comment: Size usage would be nice, I guess. I would just prefer to monitor the entire volume over each individual logical volume.

Comment: So you've got a VG, rather than an LV, and you want to know how full it is?

Comment: @womble Yes, correct, sorry for the confusion. Any thoughts?

Comment: Apart from "use a real monitoring system"?  Nothing much.  Looks like you worked out an appropriate hack for your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions. I figured out a solution that I was looking for, which was pretty simple in the end. Nothing fancy to see here but, this is what I added to zz-disk_space.conf:

```
$disk_cmd = "{ df $df_options ; echo ; } & vgdisplay"
```

Or, if you would prefer a less verbose output, I found the -s to be more concise.

```
$disk_cmd = "{ df $df_options ; echo ; } & vgdisplay -s "
```

The echo is there to add a line break between the outputs so they are visually separated and more consistent with the rest of the Logwatch report.

Answer (score 1):

To report FS usage, logwatch invokes `df` which only queries mounted filesystems. You'll need to change this logic. I suggest mounting-invoking-unmounting since there's no universal way to query an unmounted filesystem (moreover, it may be in use by something like fsck/mkfs/dd and/or unformatted so the info obtained could be garbage).

The script for you to edit is `/usr/share/logwatch/scripts/services/zz-disk-space` (and probably its configuration file, `/usr/share/logwatch/default.conf/services/zz-disk-space.conf`). Both are written in Perl.